# How to create this type of resume, or original source?

Tags: fonts, cv, resume

I am trying to create a cv like this

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\centerline{\textbf{\LARGE J}}
\vspace{1mm}
\centerline{Email : \href{mailto: hello@srk.edu}{} \hspace{1cm} Website : \href{https://www.mit.edu/~hello/}{https://www.mit.edu/~hello/}}
\vspace{2mm}

\section*{EDUCATION}

\noindent\textbf{Massachusetts Institute of Technology} \hfill Cambridge, MA \\
PhD, Electrical Engineering and Computer Science \hfill Sep 2018 – May 2023

\noindent\textbf{Massachusetts Institute of Technology} \hfill Cambridge, MA \\
MS, Electrical Engineering and Computer Science \hfill Sep 2018 – May 2020

\noindent\textbf{Tsinghua University} \hfill Beijing, China \\
BSc, Engineering Physics \hfill Aug 2014 – Jul 2018

\section*{EXPERIENCE}

\noindent\textbf{Meta} \hfill New York, NY \\
\textit{Machine Learning Engineer Internship, Instagram Reels Core Ranking} \hfill May 2022 - Aug 2022
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
    \item Mitigate Short Video Bias in Reels: Designed and developed new signals to mitigate short video bias in Reels ecosystem. Trained and deployed deep learning ranking models with new signals. Performed A/B tests to evaluate the new models. The proposed signals mitigated the short video bias (+20\% long video play), increased user time spent (+0.5\%) and achieved gains in user sessions (+0.1\%).
\end{itemize}

\noindent\textbf{Google} \hfill New York, NY \\
\textit{Software Engineer Internship, Adwords Insights Team} \hfill Jun 2021 - Aug 2021
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt]
    \item Negative Trends Mitigation: Mitigated negative reports of insight trends with a new keyword classification method in search ads.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The code doesn't generate a PDF that matches the image exactly. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should provide you with a sufficient start to replicate the output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newlist{cvitems}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[cvitems,1]{
  label=\textbullet,
  wide
}
\newlist{subcvitems}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[subcvitems,1]{
  label=$\circ$,
  nosep
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation

\NewDocumentCommand{\resumesection}{ m }{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \needspace{4\baselineskip}% If less that this space available, break to next page
  \begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
    \textsc{#1} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \par
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\newcvitem}{ m m m m }{%
%   \newcvitem{<where>}{<title>}{<location>}{<duration>}
  \item
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l }
    \bfseries #1 \\
    \itshape #2
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ r @{} }
    #3 \\
    \itshape #4
  \end{tabular}
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\LARGE J}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{r @{ : } l @{}}
      Email & who@cares.com \\
    Website & https://who.cares.com/
\end{tabular}

\resumesection{Education}

\begin{cvitems}
  \newcvitem
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {PhD, Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}
    {Cambridge, MA}
    {Sep 2018 – May 2023}
  
  \newcvitem
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {MS, Electrical Engineering and Computer Science}
    {Cambridge, MA}
    {Sep 2018 – May 2020}

  \newcvitem
    {Tsinghua University}
    {BSc, Engineering Physics}
    {Beijing, China}
    {Aug 2014 – Jul 2018}
\end{cvitems}

\resumesection{Experience}

\begin{cvitems}
  \newcvitem
    {Meta}
    {Machine Learning Engineer Internship, Instagram Reels Core Ranking}
    {New York, NY}
    {May 2022 - Aug 2022}

    \begin{subcvitems}
      \item \textbf{Mitigate Short Video Bias in Reels:}
      Designed and developed new signals to mitigate short video bias in Reels ecosystem. 
      Trained and deployed deep learning ranking models with new signals. 
      Performed A/B tests to evaluate the new models. 
      The proposed signals mitigated the short video bias (+20\% long video play), increased user time spent (+0.5\%) and achieved gains in user sessions (+0.1\%).
    \end{subcvitems}

  \newcvitem
    {Google}
    {Software Engineer Internship, Adwords Insights Team}
    {New York, NY}
    {Jun 2021 - Aug 2021}

    \begin{subcvitems}
      \item \textbf{Negative Trends Mitigation:}
      Mitigated negative reports of insight trends with a new keyword classification method in search ads.
    \end{subcvitems}
\end{cvitems}

\end{document}
```

Customizations include

- `cvitems` list for setting the first list `wide`.
- `subcvitems` list for setting the inner list.
- `\resumesection` for setting the title/section of each component.
- `\cvitem` for setting the main CV item (consisting of 4 elements).

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to get, Really useful.  can you also take a look at this question Please,

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698822/need-help-to-reproduce-simple-cv-template-in-latex