# Need help to reproduce simple CV template in latex

Tags: tables, fonts, spacing, cv, resume

I've been attempting to recreate this CV: https://rishabhjoshi.github.io/assets/pdf/vitae.pdf in LaTeX.

[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to replicate it exactly as I'd hoped, and the code seems to be growing increasingly complex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Define custom color
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}

% Remove page number
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\Huge \textbf{RISHABH JOSHI}} \\
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\end{center}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \textbf{Contact} \\
    \textbf{Information} \\
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    Google \\
    Mountain View, CA, USA
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \textbf{E-mail} : \href{mailto:rishabhjoshi@google.com}{rishabhjoshi@google.com} \\
    \textbf{Links} : \href{http://www.example.com}{Webpage}, \href{http://scholar.google.com}{Google Scholar}, \href{http://linkedin.com}{LinkedIn}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \textbf{Education} \\
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
    Carnegie Mellon University - School of Computer Science; Pittsburgh, PA \\
    \textit{Master of Science in Language Technologies} \\
    Aug 2021 \\
    CGPA : 3.94 \\
    Courses : Machine Learning, Neural Networks for NLP, Dialog Seminar, Deep RL, Multilingual NLP
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Would anyone be kind enough to assist me with a basic code to reproduce the template? I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following provides a foundation for producing the layout you are interested in.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setlist[itemize,1]{%
  leftmargin=1.2em,
  nosep% Remove vertical separation
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cvtitle}{ m }{%
  \switchcolumn[0]*% Switch to left-most column
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}% Add vertical space in left column
  {\strut\raggedright\scshape #1\par}% Set the CV title
  \switchcolumn[1]% Switch to right-most column
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}% Add vertical space in right column
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newcvitem}{ m m m m }{%
%   \newcvitem{<where>}{<title>}{<location>}{<duration>}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l }
    \bfseries #1 \\
    \itshape #2
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ r @{} }
    #3 \\
    \itshape #4
  \end{tabular}
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
  \bfseries {\Large R}{\large ISHABH} {\Large J}{\large OSHI} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\columnratio{0.15}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \cvtitle{Contact Information}
  
  \newcvitem
    {Google}
    {Mountain View, CA, USA}
    {E-mail: who@cares.com}
    {Links: \href{abc}{google.com}}
    
  \cvtitle{Education}
  
  \newcvitem
    {Carnegie Mellon University - School of Computer Science\textmd{ ; Pittsburg, PA}}
    {Master of Science in Language Technologies}
    {Aug 2021}
    {CGPA : .394}

  Courses : Machine Learning, Neural Networks for NLP, Dialog Seminar, Deep RL, Multilingual NLP
  
  \medskip
  
  \newcvitem
    {The Mother's International School\textmd{ ; Delhi, India}}
    {\mdseries\begin{tabular}{@{} l }
       Class XII, CBSE \\ Class X, CBSE
     \end{tabular}}
    {May 2014}
    {\begin{tabular}{r @{}}
       95.6\% \\ CGPA : 10/10
     \end{tabular}}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item
    Proposed an interpretable approach for knowledge proliferation in academic research articles by identifying
    key phrases using importance attribution.

    \item
    Performed a linguistic driven analysis on the characteristics of good negotiators and incorporated explicit
    strategy-sequence structure using Graph Neural Networks to improve non-collaborative dialogue systems.

    \item
    Collaborated with team Tartan to develop a conversational system in Amazon Alexa Challenge 2019 ;
    developed mini-bots and analyzed conversational story structure, reached semi-finals.

    \item
    Modeled the structure of dialogue by analyzing the flow of conversational topics and detecting noncoherence. 
    Submitted proposal for Alexa Challenge 2020.
  \end{itemize}
  
  \cvtitle{Publications}
  
  Yao Zhao, \textbf{Rishabh Joshi}, Tianqi Liu, Misha Khalman, Mohammad Saleh, and Peter J.~Liu. SLiC-HF :
  Sequence Likelihood Calibration with Human Feedback. \hfill \href{google.com}{[Paper]}
  
  Yao Zhao, \textbf{Rishabh Joshi}, Tianqi Liu, Misha Khalman, Mohammad Saleh, and Peter J.~Liu. SLiC-HF :
  Sequence Likelihood Calibration with Human Feedback. \hfill \href{google.com}{[Paper]}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Define custom color
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
% Remove page number
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\Huge \textbf{RISHABH JOSHI}} \\
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\end{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.1in}Xr}
    \textsc{Contact} & Google & \textbf{E-mail} : \href{mailto:rishabhjoshi@google.com}{rishabhjoshi@google.com}\\
    \textsc{Information} & Mountain View, CA, USA & \textbf{Links} : \href{http://www.example.com}{Webpage}, \href{http://scholar.google.com}{Google Scholar}, \href{http://linkedin.com}{LinkedIn}\\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.1in}Xr}
    \textsc{Education}
        &Carnegie Mellon University - School of Computer Science; Pittsburgh, PA & Aug 2021 \\
        &\textit{Master of Science in Language Technologies} & CGPA : 3.94 \\
    &\multicolumn{2}{X}{Courses : Machine Learning, Neural Networks for NLP, Dialog Seminar, Deep RL, Multilingual NLP}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I reduced your margins to get it similar to the link your provided.

The width of the first column (1.1in) is an approximation of what is needed. It can be modified to fit your need.

The third column is aligned to the right to put the text on the right margin of the text

the X column type use the remaining space available.

For the description, I used the multicolumn command to allow the text to span the last two columns.

The best idea for the rest of the text will be to create a new tabularx for every element of your résumé.

Hope it helps.